# What is a vector in plain C?

Tags: c, vector

I was just compiling a C file and made a typo: swapped `argc[0]` for `argv[0]`. This, of course, gave me an error message from gcc:

```
SlidingWindow_file.c:443:29: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
```

This error message makes perfect sense to me, except for one thing: What is a vector in the context of plain C (seeing as how this was a C file, not C++)? I can't seem to find any information about such a thing.

Comment: How are you compiling this.  C has no notion of vectors but if you are using a C++ compiler, I could see how you might get this error.  Try it again using a straight C compiler.

Comment: @jiveturkey an error message would not mention `std::vector` like this (instead it would complain that there is no overload available for `operator[]`)

Comment: @jiveturkey gcc has some extensions for vectorized computation...

Comment: @jiveturkey I am using a C compiler. Specifically, `make` should be running `cc -g -DDEBUG -std=c99 SlidingWindow_file.c -c` (and I have confirmed that `cc` is gcc 9.3.0 on my system).

Comment: Definitions vary, but a vector is generally just an array.  However, since C array names are just pointers to the first or [0] item, you either have to know the size, pass the size, or put the array in a struct with its size.  In C++ and OO languages, this expanded into a class, with overloading of operators like [], so the class can have an over-sized array of whatever, a capacity and a size (what is used of the capacity), constructors that set the initial capacity, inserts, updates, deletes, and automatic resizing for add on full.

Comment: Of course, the vector is expensive to delete, insert, resize, which is why they invented the linked list, tree, hash, skip list and RDBMS.  Even c has a tree, tsearch().  And trees can get out of balance, linked lists are slow to search once big, pointers bloat the data a bit, hash is not ordered/sorted, so one chooses wisely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`vector` in that error message refers to [gcc vector extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html).

Comment: Wouldn't he have to add support for vector instructions, ipp etc.

Comment: @jiveturkey gcc has support for vector instructions